# Installable Triggers for workspace Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I've been playing around with google scriptapp for a while and even created a test deployment for the cards I built.

I'm wandering if it's possible to create installable triggers for users, using `scriptApp.newTrigger()` method. How would users install this Trigger when they install my Addon? How do I test it using the test deployment method?

I have tried creating this trigger programmatically. However, since I didn't know how to install it I tested it by running it in the appscript terminal.

I expect that the function with the trigger gets registered when the user installs my addon. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the perfect solution to my problem. Since Installable triggers need to be installed once, I found [universalActions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions) a very suitable use case.

For instance, this code below will attach a `universalAction` that'll install the trigger once the user clicks on it.

```
"universalActions": [
    {
      "label": "Invoice Reminder",
      "runFunction": "createTrigger"
    }
  ]
```

[Image with universal action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59wNi.png)